# Rails force two domains to use same session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have designed the application to run on different domains under the same code base and wants to use the same session for both. If user logged in via domain1 and the same session will be used by the domain2 also. When I print the session in the console I got the below output and I stored the session id in the db.

But, I don't know how to force the domain2 to use the same session id and its respective key#values.

> {"session_id"=>"417a530e45c04811f7f391bd89675961", "site"=>"domainA",
>   "_csrf_token"=>"QKPpCxiN+8RwMt85oXoD8IQqCxkoXUCrvP76kWSJdIk=",
>   "flash"=>#, @closed=false, @flashes={},........

Comment: Are these two unrelated domains (eg foo.com and bar.com - neither is a subdomain of the other)?

Comment: It's totally different domains.(eg: foo.com and bar.com)

Comment: have you tried to export csrf token expolitly to the second session?

Comment: Yes, I tried the session id along with csrf token but no use. it's not working.